# Alternative function pointer syntax accepted by compilers with C11 standard

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I am not sure about this function pointer type declaration syntax, but it works. The syntax is just like declaring a regular old function.

```
typedef struct Element GetChildCallback(void *userdata, usize parent, usize child_no);
```

I couldn't find any information on how standard-compliant it is or what drawbacks it could possibly have.

I thought this only worked for typedefs, so I took a step further and found out this also works for regular function parameters:

```
extern inline void dmpstrn(const char *t, usize n, int printer(const char *fmt, ...));

inline void dmpstrn(const char *t, usize n, int printer(const char *fmt, ...)) {
    usize len = strlen(t) > n ? n : strlen(t);
    printer("\"");
    for (usize i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        if (t[i] == '\n') 
            printer("\\n");
        else
            printer("%c", t[i]);
    }
    printer("\"\n");
}

// ...

int main() {
    dmpstrn("Hello\nworld", UINT64_MAX, printf);
}
```

This however doesn't work for variables

```
    int printer(const char *fmt, ...) = printf; // Invalid
```

It's as if the it isn't the function pointer but the actual function, but what does it mean?

Comment: Unrelated: `usize len = strlen(t) > n ? n : strlen(t);` <<-- you seem to like strlen() a lot.

Comment: it's an example code but yeah, I know it's not a very good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function declarations used as function parameters are implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointers to the function types.

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be
> adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1

So for example these two function declarations

```
void f( void( int ) );
```

and

```
void f( void ( * )( int ) );
```

declare the same one function.

On the other hand (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
> operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
> is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
> returning type’’

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void F( int );

F display;

void g( F );

void g( F *f )
{
    int x = 10;
    
    f( x );
}

void display( int x )
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    F *fp = display;
    
    g( fp );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 10
```

Investigate the program.

Pay attention to that for example this typedef

```
typedef void F( int );
```

may be equivalently rewritten like

```
void typedef F( int );
```

Comment: To a see an example the adjusted typedef, you can also look at [section 6.7.8 example 4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Element GetChildCallback(void *userdata, usize parent, usize child_no);
```

This defines `GetChildCallback` as the actual "function type", which is different from the pointer to function type. This can be used to declare a function or form the pointer to function type, but not to define a function:

```
GetChildCallback MyButtonCB;        /* OK, declares function */
GetChildCallback MyResizeCB {}      /* ERROR, bad syntax */
struct Element MyButtonCB(void *, usize, usize) {} /* OK */
GetChildCallback  cb1 = MyButtonCB; /* ERROR, bad function definition */
GetChildCallback* cb2 = MyButtonCB; /* OK */
void add_callback(Button* button, GetChildCallback* cb); /* OK */
```

When a function type is used as a function parameter, it silently becomes the pointer to function type, just like an array parameter type becomes the element pointer type. So your example

```
inline void dmpstrn(const char *t, usize n, int printer(const char *fmt, ...)) {
```

means just the same as

```
inline void dmpstrn(const char *t, usize n, int (*printer)(const char *fmt, ...)) {
```

including the fact that `printer` in the function body is a pointer to function, so for example `(&printer)` does not act the same as `(printer)`.